# How do I find which sites a member is NOT in?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, site_details and site_members

site_details has fields such as site_id, sitename

site_members has fields such as sm_site_id, sm_user_id

I'm having difficulty in producing a list of sites that sm_user_id=1 is NOT a member of.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
From site_details
Left join site_members on sm_site_id = site_id
Where sm_user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Claus - but how does that help me find which groups sm_user_id = 1 (or any other value) is NOT a member?

Comment: I *think* the following does it: `code`SELECT site_id, sitename
FROM site_details
WHERE site_id NOT IN 
(  SELECT sm_site_id
  FROM site_members
  WHERE sm_user_id = 1 )

Comment: I avoid a subselects whenever possible. They normally reduce performance significant